# Shell scripting extra parentheses displayed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, nfs, kvm

I am a beginner in shell scripting

```
echo $ip  "node$i" >> /etc/hosts
```

Writing the above in shell leads to

```
192.168.1.2 {
192.168.1.4 node2
192.168.1.2 }
```

I dont want { and } .What should i do?

Complete program

```
read total 
number=virsh list --all |  wc -l
$number=$number+1
for i in {$number $total }
do 
virt-clone --connect=qemu:///system -o vm2 -n vm$i -f /vm$i.qcow2

ip=$(arp -an |grep "virbr0" |egrep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\. [[:digit:]]   {1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'|tail --lines=1)
echo $ip  "node$i" >> /etc/hosts
done
```

I amtrying to clone a vm and change entry in hosts file

Comment: please post complete code - which can reproduce the behaviour. what is `$ip` and `$i` ?

Comment: They are just 2 variables..

Comment: really? I would have never guessed...

Comment: `code`read total
number=virsh list --all |  wc -l
$number=$number+1
for i in {$number $total }
 do 
virt-clone --connect=qemu:///system -o vm2 -n vm$i -f /vm$i.qcow2

ip=$(arp -an |grep "virbr0" |egrep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'|tail --lines=1)
echo $ip  "node$i" >> /etc/hosts
done

Comment: Edit your question, don't put updates (especially code) in comments.

Comment: There is no way you script could have written lines you claim it has written: Your script produced `node{` and not just `{`. I don't know why you would forge the output of your script, but you're not helping. Voting -1.

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is wrong. Let's say `number=1` and `total=3`. Then

```
for i in {$number $total }
do
```

will iterate three times. The variable `i` will be set, in succession, to the values

- `{1`
- `3`
- `}`

It looks like you are trying to use brace expansion to set `i` to 1, then 2, then 3. You might have been trying to use

```
for i in {$number..$total}
do
```

but that won't work either, because in `bash`, brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. (Note that this would work in `zsh`, since its evaluation process is more complex.) With a range defined by variables, you need to use the `seq` command

```
for i in $(seq $number $total)
do
```

or a C-style loop

```
for (( i=$number; i<=$total; i++ ))
do
```

Comment: Otherwise a great answer -- but `seq` being non-standard, I'd shy away from recommending it. If you want to suggest something POSIX-compliant, `while [ $(( ( i += 1 ) <= 10 )) -ne 0 ]; do ... `

Comment: seq is running $total times instead of from $number to $total which i want

Comment: I don't understand; `seq 3 6` should produce `3 4 5 6`.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops through all the words, e.g.:

```
for i in {1 3 }; do echo $i; done
{1
3
}
```

So it will never work. Use other methods to loop, e.g. `seq 1 3`.

Comment: `for i in {1..3}` would work. But based on the OP's code (just updated) it is needed something like `for i in $(seq $number $total)`

Comment: `seq $number $total` runs the loop $total times instead of from $number to $total.I tried it out

Comment: Sure, but I don't like to post full solutions...

Comment: I have tried a lot.Please help.Thanks

Comment: @user2467973: I guess you wanted to say the opposite. Also: we don't know what you originally wanted to do (I have no idea what "total" means), so I cannot give you a full solution... Note: `echo $i` is a good starting point.

Comment: I am increasing number of instance of vms,cloning them ,filling hosts entry till it reaches total no of vms user wants...